# Redux: Why making a shallow copy of one level of the state is a mistake?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

While reading the documentation about updating nested state object in Redux, I stumbled upon this [common mistake](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html#common-mistake-2-only-making-a-shallow-copy-of-one-level), which states that doing a shallow copy of the top level object is not sufficient:

```
function updateNestedState(state, action) {
    // Problem: this only does a shallow copy!
    let newState = {...state};

    // ERROR: nestedState is still the same object!
    newState.nestedState.nestedField = action.data;

    return newState;
}
```

but I couldn't find out why it isn't sufficient, because technically it's working, As you can see in this fiddle:
https://codesandbox.io/s/D9l93OpDB

I'll be happy for further clarification/explanation regarding this statement, and also will be happy for an example of what is the best practice of updating such state objects.

Thanks!

Comment: Because state should be copied, and modifications *disallowed*.

Comment: @DaveNewton, thanks. The question is why it's disallowed. Besides the risk of having nasty bugs, does the way I modified the state object has any performance implications with React's rendering mechanism?

Comment: Because that's not how React works ¯\(°_o)/¯

Answer (score 4):

Assume you have a state object like that:

```
let state = { a: { b: 1 } };

let cp = { ...state }

cp.a === state.a //true, that means that those are the exact same objects.
```

that is because the »inner« Object (`state.a`) is added to `cp` by reference. If you now do:

```
cp.a.b = 10;
```

You change the value also in `state.a.b`. So the mistake here is: if you want to modify `state.a.b`, than you have to replace that with a new Object, having a new value like so:

```
let cp = {
  ...state,
  a: {
     ...state.a.b
     b: 2
  }
}
```

The reason for this is that you are asked to write »pure« functions, to explain consider this:

```
var a = { b: 1 };

//not a pure function
function foo (obj) {
  obj.b++;
  return obj;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) foo(a);
//a.b = 11;
```

So the object is modified each call of `foo(a)` will produce different output and modify a global variable.

The above can lead you to really nasty bugs, which are hard to find and to prevent you from running into this prefer the below.

```
//a pure function
function bar (obj) {
  return {
    ...obj,
    b + 1
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) bar(a);
//a.b = 2
```

In that case `a` is not modified, so the output of `bar(a)` will always yield the same output.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. besides the risk of having nasty bugs, does the way I modified the state object has any performance implications with React's rendering mechanism?

Comment: The primary issue is that it's likely that your connected React components that need that state will think nothing has changed, and not re-render.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering and http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ImmutableData.html .

Comment: @markerikson I don't think that's necessarily true. A new state is returned from the reducer (shallowly copied), so the state has definitely changed.

Comment: @GlennMohammad : no, any time you do not [copy all levels of nesting as part of the update](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#common-mistake-2-only-making-a-shallow-copy-of-one-level), you risk having rendering bugs.  Looking at the original question, say that a `mapState` function was extracting `state.nestedState`.  That would still be the same reference as before, and therefore the component would skip re-rendering because it _thinks_ nothing has changed.

Comment: @markerikson Ah, you're right! :) Apart from this issue, will it also cause problems with time-travel debugging? If so, all in all, would you say it won't cause problems with Redux specifically, but rather with libraries and toolings built around it?

Comment: Yes. See my post [The Tao of Redux, Part 1: Implementation and Intent](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/), where I specifically talk about [what parts of Redux and the ecosystem actually care about immutability](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/#summarizing-redux-s-technical-requirements).  Also, note that [our new Redux Starter Kit package](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org) will throw errors on mutations by default.

Comment: Fascinating posts indeed! Makes much more sense now. I'll make sure to read the whole Tao (Part 1 & 2) over the course of this week. Thanks again for the pointer, @markerikson!! 

Comment: @markerikson Oh, but wait, regarding your remark on RSK, isn't it using Immer by default so that we are free to do mutative operations in the reducers?

Comment: Yes, so _if_ you are using our `createSlice` or `createReducer` functions, it should mostly eliminate accidental mutations in reducers.  It's still hypothetically possible to mutate state elsewhere, or if you're writing reducers entirely by hand, so we have a middleware that catches those errors.