# Redux: how can mutating state by creating a shallow copy cause problems in reducer?

Tags: redux

Making a shallow copy of the state is listed in the Redux docs as [one of the common mistakes when updating nested state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#common-mistake-2-only-making-a-shallow-copy-of-one-level):

```js
function updateNestedState(state, action) {
  // Problem: this only does a shallow copy!
  let newState = { ...state }

  // ERROR: nestedState is still the same object!
  newState.nestedState.nestedField = action.data

  return newState
}
```

I still don't get why this is a problem with Redux. Doesn't reducer in Redux work synchronously such that when the reducer returns, Redux will only take into account the returned new state and discard the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my discussion with Mark Erikson (Redux mantainer) on [the related question's comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258716/redux-why-making-a-shallow-copy-of-one-level-of-the-state-is-a-mistake/44258856?noredirect=1#comment103479847_44258856), it won't cause problems with Redux, but it will break the libraries and toolings built around it (Redux DevTools, React-Redux, React, etc.) that **rely on proper use of immutability**. My highlights:

> - It's very likely that time-travel debugging and component re-rendering will break.
> - It's entirely possible for a reducer function to mutate its state, but we are not supposed to do any of those things.

Source: https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/#summarizing-redux-s-technical-requirements